# MPU6050 hanging/freezing

Tags: mpu6050

I am really short of interrupt pins on my Arduino because I have a project that already uses a lot of Arduino pins and to read DMP data from MPU6050 you always have to use an interrupt pin. I searched A LOT in the internet and many people says it's impossible to retrieve DMP data without interrupt pin. Some people also said the only way to do that would be if I could reverse engineer the MPU6050 code (which I don't know how to do).

But today, playing with MPU6050 I could finally get all of its DMP data without the interrupt pin, you just have to connect 4 pins (VCC, GND, SCL and SDA). Upload the code below to your Arduino and see that it works!

```cpp
#include "MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h"
MPU6050 mpu;
uint16_t packetSize;
uint16_t fifoCount;
uint8_t fifoBuffer[64];
Quaternion q;
VectorFloat gravity;
float ypr[3];

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  TWBR = 24;
  mpu.initialize();
  mpu.dmpInitialize();
  mpu.setXAccelOffset(-1343);
  mpu.setYAccelOffset(-1155);
  mpu.setZAccelOffset(1033);
  mpu.setXGyroOffset(19);
  mpu.setYGyroOffset(-27);
  mpu.setZGyroOffset(16);
  mpu.setDMPEnabled(true);
  packetSize = mpu.dmpGetFIFOPacketSize();
  fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();

  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  while (fifoCount < packetSize) {
    fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();
  }

  if (fifoCount == 1024) {
    mpu.resetFIFO();
    Serial.println(F("FIFO overflow!"));
  }
  else {
    if (fifoCount % packetSize != 0) {
      mpu.resetFIFO();
    }
    else {
      while (fifoCount >= packetSize) {
        mpu.getFIFOBytes(fifoBuffer, packetSize);
        fifoCount -= packetSize;
      }

      mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
      mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
      mpu.dmpGetYawPitchRoll(ypr, &q, &gravity);

      Serial.print("ypr\t");
      Serial.print(ypr[0] * 180 / PI);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(ypr[1] * 180 / PI);
      Serial.print("\t");
      Serial.print(ypr[2] * 180 / PI);
      Serial.println();
    }
  }
}
```

There is only one problem: Intermittently the Arduino hangs in the `getFIFOBytes` function for no reason. I am pretty sure it's a bug because when you call too many times `getFIFOBytes` for some reason the Arduino freezes.

Comment: Actually, removing the interrupt completly solves it all!

Answer (score 1):

I added a mpu.resetfifo after de mpu.dmpGet.... lines.
Since then 2 different systems work for at least 5 hours and with the original interupt pin attached